# ID element on the page doesn't exist when testing Ionic application using Appium

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, appium, appium-ios

I am using the Ionic 3 Framework. When I run Appium tests I receive an error like this:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 
"Keyboard is not present" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Keyboard is not present}
```

It's happening because in Xcode simulator sometimes hardware keyboard disconnects and there is no possibility to turn it on remotely.

To avoid this bug I try refer to the input field by `ID`. But when I set in Ionic app id tag like this:

```
<ion-input id="email" type="email" placeholder='Email' autocorrect="on" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="true" col-12 name="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
```

Appium doesn't see this `ID`.

How can I refer to an element on the page in Appium or how can I assign an `ID` for an element so that Appium sees it?

Thanks for any help.